# чат с момощью websocket

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Помогите разобраться с кашей в голове от изобилия всякой инфы! Я запутался, передо мной задача сделать чат как в `vk`. На сколько я понял для этого нужен `websocket`, затем при его помощи организовать этот чат.

Первый вопрос, как установить `websocket` на хостинг

Второй вопрос, как сделать сам чат с `websocket`

Я не прошу писать за меня код а дать, если есть, толковый мануал который поможет решить эти вопросы абсолютному новичку

Answer (score 0):

Все просто. На клиенте(в браузере) у нас есть активный веб-сокет, и на сервере например на `PHP` у нас есть активный веб-сокет, они общаться без перезагрузки страницы. Их взаимодействие кстати, очень схоже с взаимодействием `TCP` сокетов.

Для веб-сокетов на `PHP` нам можно или использовать готовую библиотеку, вроде `PHPDeamon`, или можем [написать](https://m.habr.com/post/209864) ручками.

Answer (score -1):

Существует over99999 и еще маленькая тележка с примерами, то чего вы хотите на NodeJS. Гуглиться все это с помощью *магических слов*: `nodejs chat`

[Вот один из 9999 примеров](https://fussraider.ru/2017/07/04/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%81-node-js-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0/)

[Что такое NodeJS, можно почитать здесь](http://nodebeginner.ru/)

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2166/266177

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов человек попросил дать ему Мануал, каким образом это возможно реализовать, я ему и скинул этот мануал, если у него возникнут какие нибудь вопросы по данному мануалу, он может оставить вопрос здесь или на том сайте.

Comment: При этом вы посылаете человека в поисковик. В чем смысл?

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Какой поисковик? Вы переходили по ссылкам?

Comment: "Гуглиться все это с помощью магических слов: nodejs chat", а сами привели всего один пример.

Comment: @ЕвгенийИванов Данное предложение: "Гуглиться все это с помощью магических слов: nodejs chat" я добавил ради того чтобы vkt смог найти альтернативу реализации, ведь данная реализация может быть ему по началу сложна и не понятна, а может и вообще статья плохая, опять же для его восприятия